# Blur and unclear content on Ubuntu gnome desktop on VM being accessed through VNC viewer

Tags: gnome, display-resolution, remote-desktop, vnc

[image: Ubuntu gnome desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS remote VM]

This is how my Ubuntu gnome desktop appears like when accessed remotely through VNC viewer. The content appears very blurry and very difficult to read.
I have set up this Ubuntu gnome desktop on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on GCP.

I have tried setting different values with this syntax and also in .vnc/xstartup script:

```
$ vncserver :1 -geometry 1024x768 -depth 24
```

But it doesn't seem to work.I have spent 2 days for setting and changing configurations and bash scripts to reach here and rectify this. I really prefer using VMs hosted on Clouds due to fast running applications on their platform unlike our own compute machines hence would really appreciate urgent help over this. This is the only bottleneck remaining to make progress in my work.

The session information for this on VNC viewer shows

size: 1024x768

pixel format: depth 6 (8 bpp) rgb222

My contents of .vnc/xstartup are :

```
#!/bin/sh
# Uncomment the following two lines for normal desktop:
# unset SESSION_MANAGER
# exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
export XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="GNOME-Flashback:Unity"  
export XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-flashback-"
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
#gnome-session --session=gnome-flashback-metacity --disable-acceleration-check --debug &
gnome-panel &
gnome-settings-daemon &
metacity &
nautilus &
```

Thanks in advance!

Result of the below command is :

```
$ lspci -nn|grep VGA
00:03.0 Non-VGA unclassified device [0000]: Red Hat, Inc Virtio SCSI [1af4:1004]
```

and

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-18-04 4.15.0-1024-gcp #25-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 24 13:09:45 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you should start session with `gnome-session --session...` line and not manually starting required applications. For example `gnome-settings-daemon` has been split in many smaller applications... And I think it is your problem!